# What is the equivalent of this construct in Delphi 2007 downward?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

In Delphi XE:

```
function ReadConfig(TextReader: TTextReader): string;
begin
  try
    Result := TextReader.ReadToEnd;
  finally
    TextReader.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Typical use:

```
var
  s: string;

  ...

  s := ReadConfig(TStreamReader.Create('MySetting.cf'));
```

Question:

What is the equivalent construct in Delphi 2007 downward.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about reading a file:

```
var
    fils: TFileStream;
    stri: TStringStream;
begin
    fils := TFileStream.Create(sFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    stri := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
        stri.CopyFrom(fils, fils.Size);
        Result := stri.DataString;
    finally
        fils.Free;
        stri.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `TStreamReader` defaults to interpretting the input data as UTF-8 encoded.  If the file really is UTF-8 and contains non-ASCII characters, then you should read the file data into a `UTF8String` instead of a `TStringStream` and then call `UTF8Decode()` to decode the UTF-8 into a `WideString`.  You can then assign that to an `AnsiString` if desired, and the RTL will convert it to Ansi accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes I want to read a config file to retrieve a string the .Net style (Embarcadero was inspired by the .Net classes TTextReader and TStreamReader). TStreamReader as a TTextReader implementation adresses character encoding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB "and the RTL will convert it to Ansi accordingly" -- when possible, of course. That said, for D2007 and below, the function works for UTF-8 if the result is declared as `UTF8String`. The caller can then call `UTF8Decode` if required. There's no reason why a `TStringStream` cannot be used to store UTF-8-encoded strings. Alternatively, the function can return a `WideString`, and assign `Result := UTF8Decode(stri.DataString);`

Comment: `TStringStream` in pre-D2009 is based on `AnsiString`. Don't get in the habit of using `AnsiString` for encoded data. It will not port to D2009+ without having to do another code re-write.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB I know and understand, but in this case, it's a question of porting code that's written for Delphi with Unicode to older versions, so there's no need for the old version of the code to be forwards compatible.